# When i run `node index.js` to start my Discord Bot it shows: Cannot find module. How do i fix this? More info provided in the body

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to run the `node index.js` to start my discord bot. I have tried almost everything i could. But it still shows:

```
PS F:\DISCORDBOTS\Beta> node index.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'F:\DISCORDBOTS\Beta\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

If you can help me it would be great.I hope i have provided enough information.

Comment: can you show your beta dir, you can also try `node .`

Comment: i tried running ```node .``` but it didnt work. also, beta dir means like the whole folder?

Comment: did you start npm(`npm init`)?

Comment: Hmm yes i did run  ```npm init```

Comment: try to write the whole path to the file `index.js` like `node F:\DISCORDBOTS\Beta\index.js`, also provide the `F:\DISCORDBOTS\Beta` in your question

Comment: The thing you said returns the same error which was generated by ```node index.js```

Comment: Provide the output of `Get-ChildItem` or `dir` command.

Comment: Uhm, i didnt understand what you said. :/

Comment: I understood what you said. When i ran dir command and pasted whatever came its saying its too long by 70 characters

Comment: is your code file called index.js

Comment: Yes the main bot file is named ```index.js```